# Java DB2 committing transaction involving row insertion

Tags: java, transactions, insert, db2, commit

I am trying to insert a row into my DB2 table in Java as a transaction. However, I am unable to commit my insertion. I would be very grateful if someone could tell me what is wrong with my code

```
public void add(Connection con,  Courier l)   {
    try{
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        con.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            ResultSet r = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM COURIER");
            r.moveToInsertRow();
            r.updateString(1,Integer.toString(l.getNr()));
            r.updateString(2, l.getName());
            r.updateString(3, l.getAddress());
            r.insertRow();
            con.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            con.rollback();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e){}
};
```

Comment: Do not swallow exceptions. At minimum log them or print them out with `e.printStackTrace()`. As an aside, the proper way to insert values is to execute an insert statement instead. Using a cursor insert is not very efficient (especially if you do an unconditional select). Once you have printed the exception stacktrace, please include the entire stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the [Inserting a row into a ResultSet in a JDBC application](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=sqlj-inserting-row-into-resultset-in-jdbc-application) example with the corresponding `enableExtendedDescribe` property setting and using the `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` value instead of `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`? Show the exception stack trace if so.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Mark Rotteveel and Mark Barinstein ! I was able to figure out what the problem was after I used e.printStackTrace(). It was just that I inserted a wrong type of value.  I also prefer using insert statement but it is a homework for uni and we are supposed to used ResultSet. Thank you once again and have a nice day!